# "Information Catastrophe" and measuring density of planets?

Tags: energy, mass, information, landauers-principle

In the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.01937.pdf the term "Information catastrophe" is explained. Suppose the later proposed experiment by this author https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0087175 turns out to be correct, then the thought experiment in the first article by the author Melvin M. Vopson would also be true / correct, so any form of artificial machinery capable of storing information in the long run as suggested in the first article above, should result in a planet with higher mass, or since the volume can not change, with higher physical density. Would this be a test to measure how advanced "the artificial created information on a planet" is, by measuring the density of this planet with a telescope or not?

Comment: The terms "over-extrapolation" and "silliness" come to mind while reading that article. Similar arguments were made for the growing number of horse-apples on public roads before the introduction of the automobile.

Comment: I don't believe that there's a way to directly measure the density of an object "with a telescope."  You can get information about its size and its mass, but even then it's tricky.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: How would you measure "without a telescope"?

Comment: @FlatterMann: Very insightful comment. Thanks for your world view.

Comment: You wouldn't.  My point is that you can't directly measure the density, you can only measure other quantities and infer the density.  And since (as has been pointed out the answers) a change in physical size is much more likely than a change in mass, there'd be no reason to actually worry about the density.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Good point, I was assuming this naively, without having knowledge of how tricky it can get.

Comment: Here's what you are looking for: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FlatterMann a very cursory search did not find that "horse-apple" means "horse poo" even though that seems to be the intended meaning.

Comment: @user253751 In some regions of the world they call it an "apple". It's about the right size, just not as delicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so any form of artificial machinery capable of storing information in the long run as suggested in the first article above, should result in a planet with higher mass, or since the volume can not change, with higher physical density.

The mass of the planet won't change. The volume may change. Hypothetically, you are converting an entire planet into a data storage system. Mass will be conserved unless you propose to use extraterrestrial materials.

Converting a tree into paper used to store information with ink does not change the mass of the planet.

The simplest example of data storage is a switch. Up is 1 down is 0. To change storage states requires energy (whatever it takes to physically move the switch) but none of that energy alters the mass of the switch. The difference in weight between the two switch states is zero.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the hypothesis made in the article is wrong. But I asked on the consequences if the hypothesis is right.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser I will give you two flash drives. One has a random pattern in it, the other a zip-file with a near perfect encoding of all of the literature in the world. Which one is which? See the problem? So what makes you think that the near random atomic patterns in Earth's crust are not an alien archive of their vast comic book collection?

Comment: Actually, I like what the article is addressing. What is the minimum volume/mass/energy required to store a piece of information? Regardless of the mechanism, mass is conserved

Comment: @FlatterMann: It is both "stored information", since your two flash drives are full. Hence the mass of both should be higher then a flash drive which is empty. That's the point. The increase in mass if information is stored. (If the hypothesis is true.)

Comment: @StevanV.Saban: So you think the hypothesis of the article is wrong?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser So now your physical theory of information storage in matter has to be extended by a "fullness" term. I have never seen that in the literature. Have you?

Comment: @FlatterMann: Well you can measure how much space is left on the hard drive, right?

Comment: @FlatterMann: My question was simple: If the hypothesis is true, does it follow that the information/mass will grow to a point where it is "measurable by telescope"?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser All correctly encoded hard drives look the same to an outside observer: like a random pattern. You are merely mistaking a poorly chosen encoding algorithm for something fundamental.

Comment: @mathoverflow "information" doesn't have a physical signature. Entropy does. A planet can be hot or cold. That is visible from afar. People need to stop mistaking an information theoretical term for a physical one.

Comment: @StevenV.Saban: Well that is the point of the hypothesis? Does the information stored in the paper with ink have any mass or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145102/discussion-between-flattermann-and-mathoverflowuser).

Comment: Whether the information has mass or not isn't the issue. It's whether that mass is created(adding mass to the planet) or converted from another mass. Mass is NOT being created.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban: No, that is not what I meant "creating mass". If the empty planet / hard drive, acquires so much information / mass that it stores this information in the planet / hard drive ,then the mass increases, if the information has mass, right?